# sprigBoot jpa connection refused to database

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

today I moved my webapp project from my desktop pc to my laptop, I literally only zipped everything and moved it to this other system,
the database name and the schema is the same, so the application properties file should still have the correct parameters to connect,
but it gives me

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I already triedup dating maven, the project, restarting the listener of the database, if I connect from sqlDeveloper it works

here's the application properties:

```
# OracleDB connection settings

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl.station
spring.datasource.username=C##GEST_SHOP
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

the only difference between the dbs is that this one on the laptop doesn't need  a password to connect, of course I aleady tried removing it from the application properties but it still doesn't work

please help

Comment: > `the only difference between the dbs is that this one on the laptop doesn't need a password`,  are you **sure** you still use `Oracle` database...

Comment: yes I went through the same process to create both dbs, Idk if it still has a password i can't remember, I know for a fact that on the desktop on sqlDeveloper to cennect it asks me the password, and on laptop it doesn't, if it has one is sthe same btw

Comment: You should disctinct the connection to the database from SQL Dveloper (that can store the password) and from that application that must allways provide all data (basically *host*, *port*, *service name or SID*, *user* and *password*. Yes, it's complicated, but the probem will be *not only* on the Oracle side;)

Comment: now im trying to solve ora-12514, i hate oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error,  this new database is on the port 1522 instead of 1521, i can't run a test tho because oracle is giving me other stupid connection errors on sqlDeveloper like doesn't know the SID which is total bs because I successfully connected before on those properties, damn I hate oracle